# unable to specify copy loop in JSON

Tags: json, azure

Hi I'm trying to add a `copyIndex` into a script so I can pass an array of vm's into it.

The full script is at:
https://pastebin.com/embed_iframe/vQyyKrYn

The error I get is:
`is not valid: The template function 'copyIndex' is not expected at this location. The function 
can only be used in a resource with copy specified.`

I do have the `copy` specified in the resource on line 44.. I think!

Any idea where I'm going wrong or how I could get this into a loop to iterate over one vm at a time.

Thanks in advance :)

Comment: did you solve this?

Comment: @4c74356b41 Hi, sort of had to put a the second part of the script into a nested template, as it was trying to loop through some resources and you can't do that twice .. which i found out eventually

Answer (score 1):

Do you need to concat the copyIndex?

Instead of:

```
[parameters('vmName')[copyindex()]]
```

Use:

```
 [concat(parameters('vmName'), copyIndex())]
```